# Java: Best way of accessing methods from far away objects

Tags: java, project-organization

I'm currently working on my first larger java project (a game) and I'm having a bit of an organisation issue already with only a few (~40) classes.
I'm organizing my game something like this:

[image: Project Organisation Model]

That seems quite organized to me as every smaller class is categorized in a larger class. Obviously classes like the `ObjectHandler` or the `Model` will contain more classes, otherwise they'd be useless.

Now my issue is: When I'm trying to access the current `PlayerSettings` from the `DynamicObjects` in the `GUI` (for example when I'm trying to get the position of the player in order to draw it on the canvas), I'd have to create a long path like this:

```
int x = gui.engine.model.objHandler.player.playerSettings.getX();
```

(For that purpose I set most parameters `public`. I could also make them accessible with `get()`-methods, but that seems even more unorganized to me)

My question is - does that look any normal or are there any better ways to solve this organisation issue?

Comment: No, that's not how you should couple your dependencies together. As a rule of thumb, "Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers". See also: [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: It is generally against the rules of programming to access everything publicly like that.... :/ but I have done it in the past when I was just learning to keep things simple. It works.... but

Comment: I'd say that for any application you want to code, use of good practices and design patterns is always the best you can do. For the case of games, why don't you try this link? It was useful to me when I created a RPG some time ago: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html

Comment: @MickMnemonic well in C++ friends have access to your private members... that breaks a lot of laws in some countries.

Comment: 1) Static things work wonders (although might not be best practice, it can shorten the amount of typing) and 2) Consider writing your function to take the player object as a parameter.

Comment: 1) But - if I'm not completely wrong - static methods can't access dynamic global parameters. So when I set `x` in `Player` by `ClassA`, I can't read that exact `x` with `ClassB`.
2) I considered that, but that would get even messier when I start to have dozens of classes in every category. I can't pass 30-40 parameters from `model` subclasses into the GUI-category.

Comment: Static methods can't DIRECTLY access dynamic global parameters - but if you pass those parameters in, that's perfectly okay.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. I want to store `xPos` in Player dynamically/globally and non-static. I want to set it with `setX(int x)` and get it with `getX()` from the outside. I cannot make these two methods static, can I? I'm pretty sure that this wouldn't work.

Comment: setX and getX should belong to the player object though, so what's the problem there? My point was that you could have Static "dynamic object class" functions that take in player objects (non static) directly

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that - no, you wouldn't want a situation where you have to de-reference six objects in order to get to the data you need.

This probably means something is wrong with how you broke up your data and functionality into classes. You would generally want to group together objects that have to talk to each other.

One practical advice is that your objects do not have to form a tree. It may make sense for the DynamicObjects to hold a reference to the PlayerSettings. This is just an example: I don't know what make sense in your application, I am just trying to point out that you don't have to think of object relationships as a tree.

And regarding get methods vs. public members: it's a Java convention to use private variables with getters and setters. It has to do with maintainability and changing the implementation in the feature. Even if that doesn't convince you, I think it's a good thing to acquire the style standards that are common in Java coding.

Comment: The problem is that most objects are related to three completely different tree pathes. The player is changed by the Controller (User input), it is read by the GUI and may also be manipulated by the Clock. Throwing all objects just randomly together and creating confusing paths between lots of classes seems even more messy to me.

Answer (score 2):

As the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) suggests, having your dependencies *loosely coupled* and as ignorant of other classes as possible, helps to make your application more maintainable. Reducing the coupling between the components enables you to rapidly refactor or change individual modules/classes.

Your GUI shouldn't know where the player settings object comes from, nor should there be a reason for the GUI to fetch the information itself -- instead, the object should be *injected* to the GUI. There are many frameworks that enable [Dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) for you, such as [Google Guice](https://github.com/google/guice), but you can also implement a simplistic version yourself by simply providing the object as parameter to the GUI, into the constructor or to a specific initialization method.

```
public class MyGUI {
    private PlayerSettings settings;
    //...    
    public void initialize(PlayerSettings settings) {
        this.settings = settings;
    }
    //...
}
```

Also, try to organize the code into meaningful packages and *reduce the visibility* of the classes within a package so that they cannot be accessed from "far away". Only expose a public API outside the package for others to use and see. The same applies for methods and fields within classes; you should not use `public` fields (aside from constants). Expose as little information outside as possible and you will be able to refactor the code within you class (or package) without breaking code that's "far away".

Comment: But that would mean that I'd have to pass dozens of objects from the `Model` category to the `GUI` category when my game grows. And even then I'd have to handle it by the `Engine` which first has to go through paths to find classes like `PlayerSettings` and then send it to the `GUI`.
In your example case it's easy to pass a PlayerSettings object to the MyGUI, but if I need much more objects from different packages it will be a lot of passing and initalizing.

Comment: This probably means that your `GUI` class has too many responsibilities -- split it up into modules/classes that have well-defined duties. I'm just pointing out some general principles here -- you might want to ask an another question regarding how to best arrange the interaction between `Model`, `GUI` and `Engine`. You're perhaps already familiar with [Model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) or related GUI design concepts?

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the MVC concept. That's why my code looks so structured - because I was trying badly to make everything with MVC. By splitting it up into modules do you mean to have subclasses in GUI (like I do with `Background`, `DynamicObjects` etc.) or by giving these subclasses to the `Engine`?

Comment: In general, I would suggest [preferring composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). You should only sub-class when there is a clear advantage from it and the child class has an _is-a_ relationship with the parent. But yes, your `GUI` should probably be _composed of_ different classes that handle user input, rendering the screen, _data-access_ etc.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to clean up dependency messes like this is to use Google Guava's EventBus. You can use it to post events and then anything subscribing to those events will act on them, all without any components knowing each other or where events come from. Its a quick way to decouple effectively and manage dependencies efficiently.

If you want something even more elegant, look at reactive programming and explore RxJava.